# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement in SpringBoot with h2 and JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

While running spring boot with h2 database and JPA i am getting below error.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
```

It is caused due to below one

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE EXCHANGE_VALUE (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, CONVERSION_MULTIPLE DECIMAL(19,2), FROM[*] VARCHAR(255), PORT INTEGER NOT NULL, TO VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID)) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table exchange_value (id integer not null, conversion_multiple decimal(19,2), from varchar(255), port integer not null, to varchar(255), primary key (id)) [42001-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:217) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
```

My hibernate class

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Exchange_Value")
public class ExchangeValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id; 
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private BigDecimal conversionMultiple;
    private int port;

    public ExchangeValue() {

    }

    public ExchangeValue(String from, String to, BigDecimal conversionMultiple) {
        super();
//      this.id = id;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.conversionMultiple = conversionMultiple;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

application.properties is below

```
spring.application.name=currency-exchange-service
server.port=8000
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop
```

Just want to know as to what i am missing in the code tried adding spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop but it did not helped.

Comment: missing part is @column

Comment: What is `FROM[*] `?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

@shubh.. Your Entity Field names are matching with [**`SQL reserved keywords`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm),

So try to change the field names otherwise use **`name`** attribute with [**`@Column Annotation`**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) (which gives alias names to the DATABASE)

```
    @Column(name="valueFrom") 
    private String from;

    @Column(name="valueTo") 
    private String to;

    private BigDecimal conversionMultiple;
    private int port;
```

Comment: Had the same problem with a attribute/column named `value` which is also a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Your Entity Field name from was matched with database reserved word from,
change the field name to another, or add a @Column annotation on that field.
Like:

...

```
@Column(name = "_from")
private String from;
```

...

Comment: Thanks this worked. I like stack overflow too much few things that u forget people can observe.

Comment: Happened to me as well using 'release'

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I did the mistake in giving the schema name in mysql database.

```
In spring.properties -> (spring boot application)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_microservice
```

Here instead of "db_microservice" I Have given the name as "db-microservice". So don't use "-". And this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

@ganesh045's response isnt actually true because hibernate's table creation query works like this: `CREATE TABLE <your_table> 'password'` for example to each of your attributes. Adding the `` to the attribute will make SQL read it `NOT` as reserved keyword. It also does the same when it queries for your select clauses inside JpaRepository. It will make a call such as this: `SELECT 'attribute' FROM <your_table>`. Your problem is most likely that you specified your schema name as kebab-case or anything which is not camelCase and snake_case. Also, with this approach you can have a table called User with attribute's `username` and `password` which actually also are `MYSQL reserved keywords`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to others observation, I got the same error when a column name contains hyphen.

Error

```
 @Column(name = "COST-CENTER")
   private String costCenter;
```

Fixed

```
  @Column(name = "COST_CENTER")
   private String costCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my problem, database name was 'user'. that's why  was giving a error. I changed database name, bug fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).